# Parse.Cloud.httpRequest call with HTTP request header

Tags: javascript, http, curl, parse-platform

I have a question for cloud code function "Parse.Cloud.httpRequest". I want to send HTTP GET request as the same as the following curl command. But it seems it is not working. If you find something wrong, please help.

`curl -H "Authorization: token xxx" "https://api.automatic.com/v1/trips"`

*Note:*

My code is like this. Then I accessed /trips.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('views', 'cloud/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.get('/trips', function(req, res) {
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: 'https://api.automatic.com/v1/trips',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'token xxx'
        },
        success: function (httpResponse) {
            console.log(httpResponse.text);
        },
        error: function (httpResponse) {
            console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
        }
    });
});

app.listen();
```

Here is a log.

```
E2014-07-16T04:10:46.102Z] v170: Ran custom endpoint with:
Input: {"method"=>"GET", "url"=>"/trips", "headers"=>{"version"=>"HTTP/1.1",   "host"=>"easyparking.parseapp.com", "user-agent"=>"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36", "accept"=>"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8", "accept-encoding"=>"gzip,deflate,sdch", "accept-language"=>"ja,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6", "cache-control"=>"max-age=0", "x-forwarded-proto"=>"http"}}
Result: success/error was not called
```

Comment: is it just a typo for this post that the url starts with 'ttps' and not 'https' ?

Comment: Thanks. There is limitation for URL, so I changed it. But now it is fine.

Comment: so what is returned?  don't just log .status, log everything.

Comment: No return. Even successful or error function is not called.

Comment: is there more code *after* this httpRequest call, outside the block?..

Comment: what appears in your cloud code logs?

Comment: added log. Please check it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this modification:

```
app.get('/trips', function(req, res) {
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      url: 'https://api.automatic.com/v1/trips',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'token xxx'
      }
    }).then(function(httpResponse) {
      console.log(httpResponse);
      res.end(httpResponse.text);
    }, function(err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.end(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: It is working but can you explain what was wrong? Your code looks different from the code in the document. https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#networking

Answer (score 0):

@Yohei, I believe you could have also done this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('views', 'cloud/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.get('/trips', function(req, res) {
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: 'https://api.automatic.com/v1/trips',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'token xxx'
        },
        success: function (httpResponse) {
            console.log(httpResponse.text);
            response.success(httpResponse.text);
        },
        error: function (httpResponse) {
            console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
            response.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
        }
    });
});

app.listen();
```

See: [Parse.com HTTPRequest {"code":141,"error":"success/error was not called"}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856595/parse-com-httprequest-code141-errorsuccess-error-was-not-called)