# Heroku CSRF and POST httpRequest

Tags: heroku, csrf, parse-cloud-code, django-csrf

I have a web crawler on Heroku and I'm trying to call the script from a POST request on Parse Cloud Code httpRequest but I receive a 403 forbidden response basically telling me the Referer Header didn't pass. How can I get past this?

Comment: Some more information about your environment would be helpful to follow up, if the answer below doesn't apply: Django version, code snippets, (Parse code; relevant settings.py); any thing you've tried so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's CSRF protection tests the `Referer` header: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/csrf/#how-it-works. Browsers typically send that header to indicate the page that originated a request, but programmatic user agents don't (`cURL`, Python `requests`, and presumably `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest`) without being told to do so.

To add custom headers to a Parse request, see: [Parse.Cloud.httpRequest call with HTTP request header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772571/parse-cloud-httprequest-call-with-http-request-header) (note the `headers` object).

That said, you also need to make sure you have a way to get the CSRF token to begin with, and include it either in a `XCSRF-Token` header or a form field (unclear from your question whether you are doing that).