# Getting 403 Forbidden error on post requests when serving django app on Amazon cloud front through heroku

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-cloudfront

I have a django app deployed in heroku, which was working previously, however after adding the Edge add-on, which serves your static files from Amazon cloudfront for caching, all of my post requests are getting 403 errors.

I do pass the csrf token correctly, as my post requests still work when not served from cloudfront, but on cloudfront I am getting the error that the CSRF Verification failed[image: CSRF Verification failed]

It also mentions that the referer header is missing, however I can see referer specified in the request headers in the network tab of the developer tools.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: Potentially relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34806206/heroku-csrf-and-post-httprequest

Comment: Did you try invalidating CF cache and then trying a POST request?

Comment: @StefanN I did invalidate the cache

Comment: @getup8 Looking into it more, it looks like CloudFront removes the referer header. I will explore this more to see, how I can change that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFront removes the referer header before sending the request to the server. The following link specifies how each header is treated: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#request-custom-headers-behavior

Using the AWS CLI, I had to configure my CloudFront distribution to forward the request header as well as the csrftoken, since cookies aren't forwarded either. Instructions can be found here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/edge#cloudfront-configuration

The ForwardedValues section of my config looked like this:

```
"ForwardedValues": {
    "QueryString": false,
    "Cookies": {
        "Forward": "whitelist",
        "WhitelistedNames": {
            "Quantity": 2,
            "Items": [
                "_app_session",
                "csrftoken",
            ]
        }
    },
    "Headers": {
        "Quantity": 2,
        "Items": [
            "Origin",
            "Referer"
        ]
    },
    "QueryStringCacheKeys": {
        "Quantity": 0
    }
}
```

I also had to update my django settings file to include

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [<CLOUDFRONT_URL>]
```

Note: Although the above instructions solved my issue in the original question, I did have to forward additional cookies such as "sessionid" and "messages" to get other features of the django app working.