# Parse.com fails when changing user password in beforeSave

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to reset the passwords of certain test users to a known state for integration testing purposes. However, the line

```
user.set("password", "testpassword");
```

Causes the save request to fail with:

> Error Domain=Parse Code=141 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 141.)"

Here is the relevant beforeSave code:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {

    var user = request.object;

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    if (user.get("username").substring(0, 4) === "test") {
        console.log("overwriting password for test user.");
        user.set("password", "testpassword");
    }

    response.success();
});
```

Comment: 141 means an error in Cloud Code, have you checked your server logs?

Comment: @TimothyWalters all of this code is cloud code, so, yes. There's nothing beyond what I've posted above.

Comment: I meant the 141 error, is that the error you are getting in the client that is doing Save/SignUp, or is that error in your server logs? You can access the server logs using `parse log` from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a full writeup on code 141 check out my other post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25360806/3204895

but in this case I'd guess that you're simply accessing the fields in a way that Parse doesn't allow, I see that you're using the master key already so the ACL shouldn't be blocking you, but try using the reserved methods for accessing username and setting the password:

```
if (user.getUsername().substring(0, 4) === "test") {
        console.log("overwriting password for test user.");
        user.setPassword("testpassword");
 }
```

if it's that the response.success is happening at the wrong point, although the code looks just fine, account for the async with a promise:

```
user.save({
    password: "testpassword"
  }).then(function(savedUser) {
    // The save was successful.
    response.success(savedUser.getUsername() + "now has a password of 'testpassword'");
  }, function(error) {
    // The save failed.  Error is an instance of Parse.Error.
    response.error(user.getUsername() + " saving failed with an error | code: " + error.code + " | message: " + error.message);
  });
```