# Issue while uploading image byte array from parse cloud function

Tags: javascript, c#, parse-platform, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin and creating cross platform mobile application.

I want to  upload an image from mobile device to parse by using cloud function.

Below is the code in C# to upload the "Byte Array" to cloud function:

```
var byteArrContent = new ByteArrayContent(App.mByteArrayOfImage);
byteArrContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/png");
dictionary.Add ("ByteArray",byteArrContent);
```

And following is the cloud function which accepts the dictionary

```
function uploadImage(request,response){  
  var file = null;     
var fileJson = {};    
file = new Parse.File("profile.png", { base64: request.params.ByteArray.toString("base64") });  
  file.save({  
            success: function(savedFile){
fileJson = {"name":savedFile.getName(),"url":savedFile.getUrl()};   
    response.success(fileJson); },
    error: function(error) { 
response.error(false,request.params.ByteArray); 
}
});
}
```

I am not able to upload the byte array. Parse cloud function (in main.js) always fails with error code 141.
Could someone please have a look and help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: Please show us the upload-function in Xamarin where you are doing the actual web request. What do you mean with "cloud function" in the second sample? Is it Node.js?

Comment: look at this ...add respose in your cloud function like this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856595/parse-com-httprequest-code141-errorsuccess-error-was-not-called